# Sore head during planking?

Tags: soreness

Just home from the gym, always finish my session with a few 10 seconds sets of planks followed by a small cool down on a treadmill. However this time round while doing my first set of 10 seconds my head felt like it was going to explode! Battled through thinking it was nothing and finished 3 sets with 5 seconds of a break in between. Now I'm sitting feeling like my brain is going to explode! Has anyone else ever felt like this and if so how do I make this stop. It's starting to annoy me cause it's not sore it's just like a pressure headache :/

Comment: You're asking us to diagnose a potential medical problem, which isn't really on topic for the site, and can't be done over the internet. If you are concerned, I would recommend you see a physician.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities. Worst common case is that it's a blood pressure issue. That's unlikely if this doesn't normally cause you problems and you're fine with other exercises. Other possibilities include bad technique. [This article](http://www.livestrong.com/article/374149-i-have-a-headache-when-doing-pushups/) is about push-ups, but it covers similar ground. Holding your breath, straining your neck or shoulders, or clenching your jaw can all lead to headaches. Lastly, there's a possibility that this is related to your horizontal position. Trying just lying down and seeing if there's an issue. If so, this might be due to blood moving toward your head or due to stuff in your sinus cavities settling.